# htaccess how to redirect if all other rules fail?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

htaccess has always given my problems.  Every time I think I understand it, htaccess goes against what I just thought I understood.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

What I want to do with htaccess is redirect URI's like:

```
www.example.com/get/something to  www.example.com/get.php/something
www.example.com/cape/something  to www.example.com/active.php/something
```

Along with a bunch of others.  I have that working great, the thing I don't have working is if none of those rules are satisfied then to redirect to my main domain.  So if I end up with a URI of **www.example.com/anythingThatIsNotDefined/anything** or just **www.example.com/anythingThatIsNotDefined** I want to redirect that to **http://www.anotherexample.com**

It is that last part I can not get to work.  My current htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^get/(.*)$ /get.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^skin/(.*)$ /active.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^cape/(.*)$ /active.php/$1 [L]
```

What do I need to modify to get anything that is not get or skin or cape to redirect to my other domain?

I will need to add more than get, skin, and cape in but once I get it working I should be able to add more in easily

Thanks in advance, this has really been stumping me.

(If this is not the right stack site I apologize, it was a 50/50 toss up between here and overflow.  I was not sure which one it belonged on.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.htaccess` uses order to determine what happens first (as do all Apache config files). In your case, you simply need to place all of your "special" rewrite rules before a catch-all rule like the one below.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.otherdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This rule basically says that for anything which doesn't exist as a hard resource (file or directory), redirect the request to http://www.otherdomain.com, including the URI string. Assuming this comes after your friendly-URL redirects, they won't be caught.

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  If I wanted to not allow any resources to be accessed (besides the ones I specify) could I just get rid of the conditions?  Edit:  I tested it without the conditions and that works perfectly for what I needed.  Is there any reason either condition should be kept if I want to disallow anything that was not specified?  Or was removing both the correct thing to do there?

Comment: Yes and no. Read this page for more info on this concept: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

Comment: Doesn't this duplicate the first slash? E.g. `/foo/bar` -> `http://www.otherdomain.com//foo/bar`